# PHP MySQL Function Return Multiple Values

Tags: php, mysql

I have the function:

```
function get_top_refs() 
{
global $db;
$top_refs = $db->EscapeString($top_refs);
$top_referers = $db->QueryFetchArray("SELECT login, COUNT(*) AS top_referers FROM users     WHERE ref > 0 GROUP BY ref ORDER BY top_referers DESC LIMIT 5");
return $top_referers['top_referers'];
}
```

And if I manually query the database it comes back with 2 columns:

```
login   top_referers
earl73      101
yadatoo     100
kamalancien 88
lolatyou    61
wesllys1as  51
```

How do I return both of these columns and then display them in a table?

Comment: I don't think that's working code.

Comment: What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: From where did `$top_refs` come?

Comment: I think so. In this line `$db->EscapeString($top_refs);` where and how does it get it's value from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your return value from `return $top_referers['top_referers'];` to `return $top_referers`

Then use this to get your values :

```
<?php
    $values = get_top_refs();
    foreach($values as $value) {
        echo $value['login']." ".$value['top_referers'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: It's displaying something now but it's displaying:

e e1 1

Comment: Can you make a `print_r($top_referers)` before the return in your `get_top_refs` function ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I'm not very experienced with this

Comment: Just put `return print_r($top_referers);` instead of `return $top_referers` and post the output

Comment: Okay I did that and now it's displaying as 
Array ( [login] => earl73 [top_referers] => 101 )

Comment: I think the `QueryFetchArray` method didn't fetch anything. =]
Can you edit your first message with the method code ?

Comment: Well it's displaying Array ( [login] => earl73 [top_referers] => 101 )  It got the username - earl73 and his referals of 101 but not the rest

Answer (score -1):

You should use $db as an argument of your function. globals is a bad idea.

```
function get_top_refs($db) 
{
    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: How can you test your function if it's global ?

Comment: Have you ever heard of POO ?

Comment: Sorry I have no clue what that is

Comment: sorry POO is in french, so for OOP see http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/